# Android Maps V2: Custom info window at custom position or work around?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, android-maps-v2

I'm able to show custom info window but not like iOs maps at diffrent position. Is there any way or workaround to show info window like this?

[image]

And can I make that show direction clickable?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a normal `View` (or some `ViewGroup` in this case) on top of the map and move camera, so that `Marker` is placed where it looks like is pointed to by this `View`.

No native (using Google Maps Android API v2) way currently, but you may track [this gmaps-api-issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5338) for when it will be possible.

Comment: I tried the same. for thaT I used projection.toScreenLocation  it returns The screen location is in screen pixels (not display pixels) relative to the top left of the map (not of the whole screen). How do I make use of it to show view at correct location?